# make -j$TOTAL_PROCESSORS

Tags: linux, makefile

what does "make -j$TOTAL_PROCESSORS" means?

Say if I have a two core processor, It will execute "make -j2". What exactly it does?

I am adding a small example below

For compiling my toolchain the script file uses -

```
pushd toolchaindir

export TARGET=powerpc-linux-gnu
export LINUX_ARCH=powerpc

TOTAL_PROCESSORS=$(grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l)
make -j$TOTAL_PROCESSORS

if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
    echo "built toolchain successfully"
else
    echo "failed during build"
    exit 1
fi
popd
exit 0
```

How it builds toolchain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make -j2` tells make that it can run two shell commands at once. Make determines whether it can do this from your makefile, so you had better write your makefiles correctly!

Consider this noddy makefile:

```
1.o: 1.c
    gcc -c 1.c -o 1.o

2.o: 2.c
    gcc -c 2.c -o 2.o

prog: 1.o 2.o
    gcc 1.o 2.o -o prog
```

If you say `make -j2 prog`, then make cleverly decides that the production of `1.o` is entirely independent of `2.o`. Thus it can run the two compiles *at the same time* without error. So it does. Make waits for *both* these compiles to finish before combining both object files into `prog` in the final link step.

Unspeakably clever, so long as you get your makefiles right (if they don't work under `-jn` then they are bad bad bad!).

Comment: I just discovered `-j` recently. Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

In one word: **yes**

It authorizes `make` to start `$TOTAL_PROCESSORS` compilations in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

It expands the environment variable TOTAL_PROCESSORS, presumably to a number which indicates how many CPUs/cores you have, and then runs make with this amount of parallel jobs.

You'll need to look at what sets TOTAL_PROCESSORS to a value.

Answer (score 0):

It reads whatever you shell variable $TOTAL_PROCESSORS is and runs that many jobs. I'm guessing that variable is set to the number of processors or cores on your machine. You can echo it's value in a shell just to be sure.